# Can't replicate data from wireshark with smartcard library

Tags: javascript, node.js, wireshark, smartcard, apdu

I have the output generated by *Wireshark* during the login to the smartcard.

[image]

I need to simulate the transmit with javascript library [smartcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartcard#iso7816applicationgetdatap1-p2). I am trying to simulate the transmit using the code below, but I am getting different values.

```
//var apduObj = {bytes: [0x00, 0xB0, 0x01, 0x94, 0x64]};
var apduObj = { size: 0x04, cla: 0x00, ins: 0xb0, p1: 0x01, p2: 0x94, le: 0x64};
const commandApdu = new CommandApdu(apduObj);
card.issueCommand(commandApdu).then(response => {
   console.log("APDU COMMAND response: " + response);
}).catch(error => {
   console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

I get this output

[image]

Can someone please help me with how to simulate the exact output?

Comment: It is unclear to me, where the separation line is between smart card communication and the transport protocol frame within your wireshark data. Note, that smart card protocols often use dynamically generated random numbers against replay attacks (which technically your approach seems to be be).

Comment: At this moment I know where was the problem. I just used a sequence of commands Login, Select and then Read binary. I mean smartcard have a login and select command in session and I can use just read binary.